# Is there a Presentation.IsFullyDownloaded property for a vsto addin in C#?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, vsto, presentation, powerpoint-addins

As per the documentation by Microsoft, there is a property to check whether the presentation is completely downloaded or not in office VBA Reference.
`Presentation.IsFullyDownloaded`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.isfullydownloaded

Is there any way to do this in a C# VSTO addin?

The 'Presentation' class in vsto solutionhas all the other properties as in the vba presentation class but not "IsFullyDownloaded".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use it in VBA for your PowerPoint installation (that means it is implemented by the host application) you can call it using the late-binding technology available in .Net via [Type.InvokeMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.invokemember?view=netframework-4.8) from any applications including VSTO add-ins.